# Keras: averaging different loss functions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras with TensorFlow backend, and want to define a custom loss function like this:

- It computes the euclidean distance between the first 2 entries of y_true and y_pred
- It computes the absolute error between the rest of the entries

Then it takes the average.

I do this:

```
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = backend.get_value(y_true)
    y_pred = backend.get_value(y_pred)

    a = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(y_pred[:2] - y_true[:2]), axis=-1))
    b = np.sum(np.abs(y_true[2:] - y_pred[2:]))
    return (a + b) / 5
```

I get an `InvalidArgumentError` when I compile the model:

```
model.compile(loss=custom_objective, optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: You can't use numpy as part of defining Keras models.

Answer (score 1):

You are using NumPy on Keras tensors, unfortunately that is a deadly combination. What you are looking for is something along the lines of:

```
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):
  a = K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred[:2] - y_true[:2]), axis=-1))
  b = K.sum(K.abs(y_true[2:] - y_pred[2:]))
  return (a + b) / 5 # these operators work on tensors
```

Comment: Tensors `y_pred` and `y_true` usually have 2 dimensions in Keras. Use `y_true[:, :2]` and `y_pred[:, :2]` instead.